# Read txt file and parse the values to bash script

Tags: linux, bash, variables, loops, while-loop

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='config.txt'

while filename = read -r line do
        for file in $(find /home/user/ftpuser -maxdepth 1 -name "*.[ew]ar" -type f); do
        /apps/oracle/jrockit/4.1.0-1.6.0_37-R28.2.5-x86_64/bin/java -jar ../windup-cli-0.6.8/windup-cli.jar -javaPkgs com.lib - input ../ftpuser/ -output ../reports/ "${file}"
            cp "${file}" /home/user/ftpuser/scanned/
        done < "$filename"
        sleep 60
done
```

The script needs to find two types of files into a directory. An .ear and a .war file. Once it finishes it executes one command which is making reports of the files that we have found before in a directory called /reports. The next step is to copy all the files that we have found in the step number one, to a directory called scanned. My problem focuses in the command I am executing to make the reports. In this command there is somewhere the -javaPkgs com.lib. I need to read this value from a configuration file.The script needs to read the values from the configuration file and assign them to the script, so each time we change the values in the configuration file we can execute the script with different values. My question is how can I do this? I have tried above to do something but it doesn't work.

Below you can also see the configuration file.

config.txt

```
targetHostName=10.125.162.132
packages=com.ibm,com.jboss   
path=/home/user/ftpuser/reports
username=root
password=root
```

Comment: `while filename = read -r line do` -- what is this supposed to do?

Comment: I was hopping that this will read the config.txt But it doesn't.

Comment: You can read the file as a bash script to get the variables from it like `source "config.txt"` and then like `find $path ...` if thats whwat you want to do?

Comment: Partially yes. I will try to make it more clear. In the config.txt file you can see all these values. targetHostName, packages e.t.c. What I need to do is to write a script that it reads the values from the config.txt and then does the procedures I have mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

The following would give you a *list* of packages for which you want the reports:

```
grep "^packages" config.txt | cut -d= -f2 | tr ',' ' '
```

Based on this, you can loop for values in the list:

```
filename="config.txt"
for i in $(grep "^packages" $filename | cut -d= -f2 | tr ',' ' '); do
  for file in $(find /home/user/ftpuser -maxdepth 1 -name "*.[ew]ar" -type f); do
    echo /apps/oracle/jrockit/4.1.0-1.6.0_37-R28.2.5-x86_64/bin/java -jar ../windup-cli-0.6.8/windup-cli.jar -javaPkgs ${i} - input ../ftpuser/ -output ../reports/ "${file}"
    cp "${file}" /home/user/ftpuser/scanned/
  done
done
```

Comment: I will check it and I will let you know!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I see how you could use it:

```
#!/bin/bash

config_file='./config.txt'  ## If you want to pass your configuration as an argument, use config_file=$1

. "$config_file"

while read -r file do
    /apps/oracle/jrockit/4.1.0-1.6.0_37-R28.2.5-x86_64/bin/java -jar ../windup-cli-0.6.8/windup-cli.jar -javaPkgs com.lib - input ../ftpuser/ -output ../reports/ "${file}"
    cp "${file}" /home/user/ftpuser/scanned/
    sleep 60
done < <(exec find /home/user/ftpuser -maxdepth 1 -name '*.[ew]ar' -type f)
```

The script would read `config_file.txt` as another source file assigning values to variables. With that you could already use those variables as `$targetHostName`, `$packages`, `$path`, `$username` and `$password`.